# read in a file from url or filesystem to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, file-io

I am trying to read in a file from a file on my computer and store in in a variable.
I am currently trying:

```
var fr = new FileReader;

fr.onload = function() {

    //variable to hold file
    var data = fr.result;

    var c=document.getElementById("cvs");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,200,180);
};

fr.readAsDataURL("encryptedImage");
```

this does not work. I need to do this do i can decrypt an encrypted image on my file system. I have already turned of the security so my file system can be read from a browser.

any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: in Firefox i get NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMFileReader.readAsDataURL].

Comment: in safari i don't get any

Answer (score 0):

From here it looks like you want to load the local file by passing a String to readAsArrayBuffer(), but it exspects a blob or file object. The file can be loaded via the browsers file dialog.
Steps are : Select the file, load the file via fileReader asArrayBuffer or asDataURL or asBinaryString ... and manipulate or use the data in your code.

For this example it creates an Image from the local file and draws it onto the canvas (if it's of correct mime type "image.*" however).

I'm not sure what kind of encoding/decoding you want to apply. But for custom manipulation of data I would recommend using ArrayBuffers and TypeArrays.

The example with FileReader.readAsDataURL(): http://jsfiddle.net/uvmD7/

```
<body>
  <canvas id="cvs" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
</body>
```

And the script:

```
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

var fr = new FileReader();

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
};

fr.onload = function(evt) {
    // do sth with it
    var data = evt.target.result; //fr.result 
    img = new Image();
    img.src = data; 
    //  draw after load
    img.onload = function() {
       var c=document.getElementById("cvs");
       var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
       ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,200,180);      
    };
};
```